# How Can I show data to tableView From Array which belong in model array object in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a model object it have a array i m populating data by indexPath.row than i need to send every section array to another tableView but it sending me random data how can i send specific selected rows array to next tableView ? please help me to make understand ..

here is My Model Object :

```
class ProductModel {

    var name:String
    var option: [String]
    var image:UIImage
    init(name:String,option:[String],image:UIImage) {
        self.image = image
        self.name = name
        self.option = option
    }
}
```

Here is my Model Object :

```
class Data {

    static var product = [ProductModel]()

}
```

Here is Data function For Append Data

```
static func read(compleationHandler:@escaping () -> ()) {

    let hospitalList:[String] =  ["A","B,C"]
    let hospitalTwo:[String] = ["Sharee bangla","National Park","bangladesh medical"]
    let hospitalThree:[String] = ["NSU","MIU","UIU","AIUB"]
    let hospitalFour:[String] = ["Dhaka","Comillah","Borials"]
    let hospitalFive:[String] = ["iPhone","iPad","iMac"]

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {


        if Data.product.count == 0 {

            Data.product.append(ProductModel(name: "Mahmud", option: hospitalList, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "radio")))
            Data.product.append(ProductModel(name: "Rangon", option: hospitalTwo, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.on.fw")))
            Data.product.append(ProductModel(name: "Saikot", option: hospitalThree, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Unit.fw")))
            Data.product.append(ProductModel(name: "Ratul", option: hospitalFour, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Region.fw")))
            Data.product.append(ProductModel(name: "Jubayer", option: hospitalFive, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "add-note.fw")))

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            compleationHandler()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is first ViewDidLoad and a global array for store cell arary :

```
class ModelTableView: UIViewController {
    var optionData:[String] = [String]()


    @IBOutlet var ModelDataTableVIew: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         ModelDataTableVIew.delegate = self
        ModelDataTableVIew.dataSource = self
        ModelFunction.read { [weak self] in
            self?.ModelDataTableVIew.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

Here is cellForRowAtIndex here i created in my label i add a tap Gesture .when user click it show another tableView with this cell array data

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row  == Data.product.count {
            let cell = ModelDataTableVIew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "modelCellBtn") as! ModelCellBtn
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = ModelDataTableVIew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "modelCell") as! ModelCell
            cell.configureCell()
            optionData = Data.product[indexPath.section].option
            let tapGeshture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(_:)))
            cell.optionLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGeshture)
            cell.nameImage.image = Data.product[indexPath.row].image

            return cell
        }
```

Here is prepare Segue and sending Data to next view controller :

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "option") {
            let dest = segue.destination as! OptionViewController
            dest.data = optionData

        }

    }
```

Here is my nextViewController (For show option Data):

```
class OptionViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

        var data:[String] = []

        @IBOutlet weak var optionTableView: UITableView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            optionTableView.delegate = self
            optionTableView.dataSource = self
            print(data)
            optionTableView.reloadData()
            ModelFunction.read { [weak self] in
                self?.optionTableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
```

Here option View Controller and in this controller i want to show retrieved array show in tableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = optionTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "optionCell") as! OptionCell
        //cell.textLabel?.text = Data.product[indexPath.section].option[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
    }
```

But its showing me single section data in my tableView ..

Comment: First of all **never** name a custom class `Data`. It could interfere with the internal struct `Data`. And variable names are supposed to start always with a lowercase letter. And in table view delegate methods use always the passed `tableView` instance rather than the hard-coded properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the optionData in your cellForRow method, which is always taking the lastVisible data, You should take the optionData in your didSelectRowAt method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("didselect")
    optionData = Data.product[indexPath.row].option
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "option", sender: self)
}
```

Try and share your results.

Comment: Its sending First Section Data to next viewController (tableView)  / A B,C

Comment: You should comment the gesture part from your cellForRow. These two line. let tapGeshture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(_:)))
            cell.optionLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGeshture).

Comment: Did it but Same Result i think this two line not part of sending data

Comment: yes, that are not part of sending data, but I thought may be something wrong in tapped(_ :) method.

Comment: what is there in tapped(_ :) method, can you please post that code to better understand the issue.

Comment: Nothing in there  @objc func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Tapped")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "option", sender: self)

    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178600/discussion-between-bhavin-kansagara-and-ekramul-hoque).